# Sorting DIVs in a DIV using jQuery

Tags: jquery, sorting

I looked at several entries on here related to this, but none specifically for alphanumeric sorting.  Tried A LOT of ways today, but got no where, so I looking for help.

HTML

```
<div id="chartEntries">

  <div class="divEntry" rval="BBB">
        <div class="ori" style="display:none;">BBB</div>
         <h3>Value</h3>
         <span>BBB - I should come in 2nd.</span>
  </div>
   <div class="divEntry" rval="DDD">
       <div class="ori" style="display:none;">DDD</div>
         <h3>Value</h3>
         <span>DDD - I should come in 4th.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="divEntry" rval="AAA">
      <div class="ori" style="display:none;">AAA</div>
         <h3>Value</h3>
         <span>AAA - I should come in 1st.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="divEntry" rval="CCC">
      <div class="ori" style="display:none;">CCC</div>
         <h3>Value</h3>
         <span>CCC - I should come in 3nd.</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

I want to return the sorted .divEntry DIVs unchanged back into the #chartEntries DIV.

Tried

```
function sorter(a,b){
    return $(a).data('rval') > $(b).data('rval');
}

var orderedDivs = $('.divEntry').sort(sorter);
$("#chartEntries").html(orderedDivs);
```

also tried with .getAttribute('rval').  Any thoughts?

jsFiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/mweidlick/tb6xpfkk/40/

Comment: When adding non-standard attributes to elements you should prefix them with `data-`.

Comment: Thanks for the standardization tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had it mostly correct, except you didn't need to turn your variables `c` and `d` into jquery objects for `localeCompare`, they're already strings so you can simply do:

`output = c.localeCompare(d);`

https://jsfiddle.net/tb6xpfkk/41/

Comment: I knew I was close.  Thanks for the 'second set of eyes'.

Answer (score 1):

When creating new attributes, prefix them with `data-`

```
<div id="chartEntries">
  <div class="divEntry" data-route="LAXSFO">
    <h3>LAXSFO</h3>
    <span>190 - I should come in 2nd.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="divEntry" data-route="YYZJFK">
    <h3>YYZJFK</h3>
    <span>300 - I should come in 4th.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="divEntry" data-route="ABLDFW">
    <h3>ABLDFW</h3>
    <span>100 - I should come in 1st.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="divEntry" data-route="MSPSTL">
    <h3>MSPSTL</h3>
    <span>290 - I should come in 3nd.</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function(){
    var entries = $('.divEntry').get();

  entries.sort(function(a, b){
    return $(a).data('route').toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).data('route').toUpperCase());
  });

  $('#chartEntries').append(entries);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tb6xpfkk/42/

Comment: Thanks for the standardization tip.  So, after I change them to 'data-route', I can still reference them as .data('route') and not as .data('data-route')?

Comment: @MichaelW yeah data() takes care of the data- for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your sorter function a bit to use a comparison similar to the way you're representing in your question and it worked.

```
function sorter(a, b) {
    var c = a.getAttribute('route');
    var d = b.getAttribute('route');
    var output = c.toLowerCase() > d.toLowerCase();
    return output;  
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4mt5p3p1/

I've noticed that in the example you've given, you're using `data()` but your attributes are not `data-rval`, which would justify why the example in your question won't work. But you said that you also tried `getAttribute` which should do the trick as you can see in the jsfiddle (so I'm not sure why it didn't work for you before).

Answer (score 0):

You already have extracted the route value using `getAttribute`. So you do not need to convert into another jquery object to compare the values. Another way to do this without `localeCompare` would be while during comparison, you can use `$.after` to move the elements where they are needed.

```
function sorter(a, b) {
  var c = a.getAttribute('route');
  var d = b.getAttribute('route');
    output = c.toUpperCase() > d.toUpperCase();  
  if(output)
      $(b).after(a);    
};

var sortedDivs = $(".divEntry").toArray().sort(sorter);
$.each(sortedDivs, function (index, value) {
  $(".divEntry").toArray().sort(sorter);
// $("#chartEntries").append(value)
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/tb6xpfkk/43/